# Replace second to last value of axis with unit

Tags: gnuplot, axis-labels

My university has strange rules regarding diagrams in scientific papers. It requires the second to last value of an axis to be replaced with the unit.

For example a length axis going from 0 to 5 m has to look like this:

0    1    2    3    m    5

Supposedly this is possible with gnuplot, but I couldn't find a way. Is there any way or should I just use the magic of image editing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set manual xtics which replace the default ones if they coincide.

```
set xrange [0:5]
set xtics add ('m' 4)
plot x
```

Unfortunately you cannot specify the "second last" to be replace automatically.

[image]

Comment: Using my answer to [How to get the distance between automatic generated gnuplot tics?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25982518/2604213) you could possibly also get an automatic solution to your problem.