# How to get the distance between automatic generated gnuplot tics?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm  doing a large number of plots using gnuplot. As the data range (for both x and y axis) is variable for each plot, I need to let gnuplot auto set both range and tics. However, I need to place a defined grid under the plot, with horizontal lines each 1/8 unit and verical lines 1/4 unit. As I let gnuplot decide where to place tics, I don't know the distance (in units) between two tics and hence, I don't know the number of subdivisions that I should made in m{x|y}tics to have the desired output.

E.g.: If I have a ytic every two units, I need to "set mytics 8". If I have a ytic every unit, I need to "set mytics 4".

So, there is someway to obtain the distance between auto-placed tics? Or even the number of plotted tics?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the distance between auto-placed tics, use the following code (save as `ticstep.gp`):

```
xr = abs(max_value - min_value)
power = 10.0 ** floor(log10(xr))
xnorm = xr / power # approximate number of decades
posns = 20.0 / xnorm;

if (posns > 40) {
  tics = 0.05
} else {
  if (posns > 20) {
    tics = 0.1
  } else {
    if (posns > 10) {
      tics = 0.2
    } else {
      if (posns > 4) {
        tics = 0.5
      } else {
        if (posns > 2) {
          tics = 1
        } else {
          if (posns > 0.5) {
            tics = 2
          } else {
            tics = ceil(xnorm)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
ticstep = tics * power
```

This ought to be equivalent to the internal gnuplot-code to determine the ticstep (see [axis.c, line 677](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/gnuplot-main/ci/master/tree/src/axis.c#l677).

To get the ticstep only, you can use `stats` to get the respective data values:

```
stats 'file.txt' using 1 noutput
max_value = STATS_max
min_value = STATS_min
load 'ticstep.gp'
print ticstep
```

To get the number of plotted tics you need the autoextended axis limits (unless you use `set autoscale fix`). For this you can plot with the `unknown` terminal to get e.g. `GPVAL_Y_MAX` and `GPVAL_Y_MIN`:

```
set terminal push # save current terminal
set terminal unknown
plot 'file.txt' using 1
set terminal pop # restore terminal
max_value = GPVAL_Y_MAX
min_value = GPVAL_Y_MIN
load 'ticstep.gp'

print sprintf('ticstep = %f', ticstep)
numtics = int((xr / ticstep) + 1)
print sprintf('numtics = %d', numtics)
```

Comment: with ticstep.gn you saved my day. Again :) It helped me to generate custom ytics

Comment: @taiko Great that it helped you

Comment: yeah. As the asker I needed to generate more plots with different data ranges. Autoscale wasn't working to my satisfaction. With STATS_min, STATS_max and a bit finetunnig of your ticstep function I was able to do " set ytics STATS_min,ticstep, STATS_max ".

Comment: @Christoph, just for completeness, be aware that `floor(log10(xr))` does not always give you the expected order of magnitude (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/55130265/7295599). Well, it's not tragic, in worst case you get too many tic labels ;-)