# How gnuplot choose the interval between tics?

Tags: gnuplot

do you know how gnuplot choose the interval's value between two tics and/or if it's possible to access to this data ?

My code produces datas that I scale doing `set yrange [MIN:MAX]`. But, most of the time, with this method, there's an extra space on top of the last ytic. For exemple : with values from 20 to 20.032, gnuplot will start ytics by 20 and end by 20.03 with intervals of 0.005. The extra space is 0.002.

I would like to automatically add an extra interval in order to close the axis by a ytic. For the exemple above, I have to add an interval of 0.005. How can I know automatically this value from my datas ?

Thank's in advance

PS : I know the `set ytics start,interval,end` manual command but this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't completely understand your question, but maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/25989366/2604213 helps you

Comment: That's exactly what I looked for, and the answers is very clear ! Thank you very much @Christoph !