# Inconsistency with gnuplot format specifiers %t and %T?

Tags: gnuplot, number-formatting

If you use the gnuplot format specifiers `%t` and `%T`, you will observe some inconsistent behaviour.

```
### gnuplot format specifiers

Numbers = "94 95 99 100 101"

do for [n in Numbers] {
    print gprintf("%3g",n)." = ".gprintf("%t",n)." x 10^".gprintf("%T",n)
}

Mantissa(n) = real(n)/10**floor(log10(n))
Power(n) = floor(log10(n))
do for [n in Numbers] {
    print gprintf("%3g",n)." = ",Mantissa(n)," x 10^",Power(n)
}
### end of code
```

Result:

```
 94 = 9.400000 x 10^1
 95 = 0.950000 x 10^2
 99 = 0.990000 x 10^2
100 = 1.000000 x 10^2
101 = 1.010000 x 10^2
 94 = 9.4 x 10^1
 95 = 9.5 x 10^1
 99 = 9.9 x 10^1
100 = 1.0 x 10^2
101 = 1.01 x 10^2
```

Why, for example, is `95` shown as `0.95 x 10^2` instead of `9.5 x 10^1`?
What is the reasoning behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, besides `gprintf("%t",95)` and `gprintf("%T",95)` not showing the expected mantissa and power, also the formula `floor(log10(n))` sometimes does not show the correct power of `n`. (see here: [gnuplot: how to get correct order of magnitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55231202/7295599))

Suggestion for workaround: the following formulas make a detour via string formatting, but at least they should always give the correct mantissa and power.

```
Mantissa(n) = real(sprintf("%.15e",n)[1:strstrt(sprintf("%.15e",n),"e")-1])

Power(n) = int(sprintf("%.15e",n)[strstrt(sprintf("%.15e",n),"e")+1:])
```

In the longterm, the functions `gprintf("%t",...)`, `gprintf("%T",...)` should be fixed in the gnuplot source code.