# gnuplot: how to get correct order of magnitude?

Tags: gnuplot, logarithm, rounding-error

This question/issue is maybe related somehow to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55130265/inconsistency-with-gnuplot-format-specifiers-t-and-t).

If you type:

`print log10(1e7)` you will get `7.0`.

`print int(log10(1e7))` you will get `7`.

However, if you type

`print log10(1e6)` you will get `6.0`.

`print int(log10(1e6))` you will get `5`.

These are probably rounding errors related to `log10` and cannot(?) be avoided.

Because if you type

`print sprintf("%.20e",log10(1e6))` gives `5.99999999999999911182e+00`

`print sprintf("%.20e",log10(1e7))` gives `7.00000000000000000000e+00`

You can extend and summarize this as a plot:
Code:

```
### power problem in gnuplot
reset session
set colorsequence classic
set key left
set samples 41

set xrange[-20:20]
plot int(log10(10**x)) w lp pt 7,\
    x w lp pt 7
### end of code
```

Result:

[image]

You will see that in irregular distances there are differences between the expected and the obtained result.

So, I am still missing a function which gives me always the correct order of magnitude. Maybe rounding all numbers first to 15 decimal places? Any other ideas?

Comment: Printing a double with format "%.20e" is just asking for garbage.  An IEEE 64-bit floating point number only encodes 53 bits (15-16 decimal places) of precision.  Limiting the requested precision to 15 decimal places is not "rounding", it is just acknowledging what information is actually present.

Comment: I agree. By the way, what does `sprintf("%.0e",5.99)` do? It seems to round, not to truncate. Would I always get the expected integer with this function?

Comment: "%.0e" suppresses the decimal point.  See documentation for libc printf family `man 3 printf`

Comment: @Ethan What do you mean with "suppresses the decimal point"? Neglecting the decimals after the comma or rounding? `"%.0e"` seems to round (at least in gnuplot). `sprintf("%.0e",5.50)` gives `6e+00` and `sprintf("%.0e",5.49)` gives `5e+00` and `sprintf("%.0e",5.4999999999999999)` gives `6e+00` as well.

Comment: "suppresses the decimal point" means it does not print a decimal point. `sprintf("%.0e",5.999999999999999)` gives `6e+00` (no decimal point). `sprintf("%e",5.999999999999999)` gives `6.00000e+00`.

Comment: @Ethan, ah, yes of course. Sorry, I was on the wrong track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that you are not dealing with more than 12-15 digits (or as @Ethan says more than 15-16 digits in a 64 bit system is nonsense anyway), the following function should give the correct order of magnitude as integer. I just tested a few examples and compared it with other "straightforward" methods. Please prove the function right or wrong.

```
### get the correct power of a number with gnuplot

CorrectPower(n) = floor(log10(n*(1+1e-15)))
IncorrectPower1(n) = floor(log10(n))
IncorrectPower2(n) = floor(gprintf("%T",n))

Numbers = "1e-6 1e-4 0.001 0.01 1e-2 1000 1000000 -1e-6 -1e-9 0.99 95 990"

print " Number    cP  icP1 icP2"
do for [i=1:words(Numbers)] {
    n = word(Numbers,i)
    print \
        sprintf("%7s:%5d%5d%5d", n, CorrectPower(n), IncorrectPower1(n), IncorrectPower2(n))
}
### end of code
```

Result:

```
 Number    cP  icP1 icP2
   1e-6:   -6   -5   -6
   1e-4:   -4   -3   -4
  0.001:   -3   -2   -3
   0.01:   -2   -1   -2
   1e-2:   -2   -1   -2
   1000:    3    2    3
1000000:    6    5    6
  -1e-6:   -6   -5   -6
  -1e-9:   -9   -8   -9
   0.99:   -1    0    0
     95:    1    1    2
    990:    2    2    3
```

**Addition:** For what it's worth, another function to get correct power as integer:

`CorrectPower2(n) = int(sprintf("%.15e",n)[19:])`