# Gnuplot: power notation axis

Tags: gnuplot

I set the y-axis in power notation (1.0e+5 or 1.0 * 1.0^5) but I would like to report the power just on top of the axis to save space. In particular I would like to report at the end of the axis as reported in the link

[image: https://imgur.com/a/eDc0FW2]

Answer (score 2):

Try use this commented code:

```c
# Creating some 'x y' data to plot and
# save output using 'table' and 
# datablock named 'data'
set table $data
    plot (1E-5 + sin(x)*1E-5)
unset table

# Performs statistics using 'y' column 
# to find max value, turn off output, and
# set prefix name 'data' to stats results
stats $data u 2 nooutput name 'data'

set tmargin at screen 0.94    # Change the top margin

# Define a label containing the power to base 10
# of max value from data and put on top-left
# using the same value of top margin 
# but using offset on y axis
set label gprintf('×10^{%T}',data_max) at graph 0.0, screen 0.94 offset 0,0.75


set format y '%.2t'  # Format for 'y' values using mantissa 
                     # to base 10 and 2 decimal places

set xlabel 't'       # label to 'x' axis
set ylabel 'Ω'       # label to 'y' axis
unset key            # Turn off key (legend)
set tics nomirror    # Turn off upper and right tic marks

# The plot itself
plot $data using 1:2 w l
```

Produces

[image: plot]

Comment: Nice and well documented code! Just be aware that there is some inconsistency with `gprint()` and `%t` and `%T`. For example, `print gprintf('%T',95)` will give the wrong result. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/55130265/7295599

Answer (score 1):

I guess is very common to put the prefactor in the label (instead of top of the axis). If you absolutely need it on top, let me know. One way would be the following. There would also be ways to determine the prefactor automatically.

**Code:**

```
### prefactor for axis
reset session

Power = 5
set format y "%.2f"
set ylabel sprintf("Ω [10^%d rpm]", Power) enhanced

f(x) = 3e4*sin(x)+1.2e5

plot f(x)/10**Power w l notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you theozh. Probably it's not possible to do what I wanted with gnuplot. Anyway, I tried >>plot "data.dat" using 1:2/10**5 with lines linestyle 1<< but it seems something is not going well plotting the graph. Have you any idea why?

Comment: Of course, it is possible with gnuplot (as @GRSousaJr shows). I used a function, in case you have data from a file you need `plot 'data.dat' u 1:($2/10**5) w l ls 1`. If you do some calculations with columns you have to put it into `()` and use e.g. `$2` for column 2.