# gnuplot: using format data types to seperate a number?

Tags: types, format, gnuplot

I want to seperate the given range of a logarithmic scale, especially the minimum value.
e.g. x_min= 0.2 and I want to get "2" and "-1" as parts of 2*10**(-1) for further usage. From manual, that would be %t and %T. I tried using print ("%T", x_min) but I just get x_min itself, no matter which type I set in print. Is there any way to do this in gnuplot?

Comment: You can to use `gprintf` to do this. But just be aware that there is some inconsistency with `gprintf()` and `%t` and `%T`, [as point up by @theozh](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55130265/11369382).

Comment: just saw, print has to be before gprintf. i'll give it a try, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@GRSousaJR already mentioned [some inconsistencies with `gprintf()` and `%t` and `%T`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55130265/7295599) in the comments. I quickly tested with gnuplot 5.2.8, the inconsistencies are still there. A cumbersome solution is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55428661/7295599).

**For example:**

`print gprint("%t",95)` gives `0.95` and `print gprintf("%T",95)` gives `2`.

So, `95 = 0.95 x 10^2` is not wrong but the expected result would be `9.5 x 10^1`.

But now, if you use for example `%.3t` instead of `%t` you will get *wrong* results.
Maybe someone can explain this?!

So in summary: 
(It's getting a bit lengthy because `gprintf()` only allows for one parameter.)

**Code:**

```
### inconsistency in gprintf with %t and %T
reset session

array Numbers = [0.95, 9.5, 95, 995, 9995]

print "gprintf with %t"
do for [i=1:|Numbers|] {
    print gprintf("% 8g",Numbers[i])." = ".gprintf("%t",Numbers[i])." x 10^".gprintf("%T",Numbers[i])
}
print "gprintf with %.3t"
do for [i=1:|Numbers|] {
    print gprintf("% 8g",Numbers[i])." = ".gprintf("%.3t",Numbers[i])." x 10^".gprintf("%T",Numbers[i])
}
print "gprintf with %.0t"
do for [i=1:|Numbers|] {
    print gprintf("% 8g",Numbers[i])." = ".gprintf("%.0t",Numbers[i])." x 10^".gprintf("%T",Numbers[i])
}
### end of code
```

**Result:** (with gnuplot 5.2.8)

```
gprintf with %t
    0.95 = 9.500000 x 10^-1
     9.5 = 9.500000 x 10^0
      95 = 0.950000 x 10^2    # somehow correct but not the expected result
     995 = 0.995000 x 10^3    # somehow correct but not the expected result
    9995 = 0.999500 x 10^4    # somehow correct but not the expected result
gprintf with %.3t
    0.95 = 9.500 x 10^-1
     9.5 = 9.500 x 10^0
      95 = 9.500 x 10^2    # simply wrong
     995 = 9.950 x 10^3    # simply wrong
    9995 = 9.995 x 10^4    # simply wrong
gprintf with %.0t
    0.95 = 9 x 10^-1
     9.5 = 9 x 10^0
      95 = 1 x 10^2    # somehow ok, rounded. But why not 9 x 10^1, similar to 9.5?
     995 = 1 x 10^3    # ok, rounded
    9995 = 1 x 10^4    # ok, rounded
```

Comment: I didn't check but maybe you have to use the same parameter for %T? since this value doesn't change, they easily misfit?

Comment: Do you mean, e.g. `%.3T`? I don't think so, it wouldn't make too much sense, because power should be an integer number.